# SVN merge revision ranges: how does svn merge know which revisions it needs to merge?

Tags: svn, merge

My question is a little convoluted so please bear with me.

I created a branch to do some development, and now I would like to merge all of the changesets onto trunk.  At two points in the branch, I merged changes from the trunk into the branch to get up to date again.

```
mkdir trunk
cd trunk
svn co $TRUNK .
```

I created the branch at **r2797**, and my last commit to that branch was **r3151**.

Now when I come alone to merge the branch into my working copy trunk:

```
svn merge $BRANCH .
```

I get the following message:

```
--- Merging r2798 through r3022 into '.':
```

This is weird, why isn't it applying all of the change sets until r3151?

so I tried specifying the revisions to the merge command.

```
svn merge -r2797:3151 $BRANCH .
```

But I get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN uses the svn:mergeinfo property to track merges. It probably doesn't merge the other revisions because they have been merged already.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo for details.

Comment: Thanks, I merged parts of the branch in before, so it is a bit screwed up.